# Angular js Google maps infoWindow

Tags: angularjs, maps, infowindow

I've read all about on this subject but I'm still not getting the results which actually work.
I'm creating an event handlers inside a loop for gmaps markers to open a infowindow and load a div inside there as content with ng-include directive for templating. ng-include does not work.

```
var content = '<div ng-include src="/templates/marker_infoview.html"></div>';
var compiled = $compile(content)($scope);

var markerEventListener = google.maps.event.addListener(markers[u], 'click', function() {
    $scope.$apply();
    stepDisplay.setContent(compiled[0]);
    stepDisplay.open($scope.map, markers[u]);

});
```

When I click on a marker an empty infoWindow opens. It doesn't even look like the content string defined earlier.
Logging compiled[0] it in a console I get: "< !-- ngInclude:  -->"

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx see the compile section at the end, this may help you out

Comment: it did not help me. or maybe i wasn't using it correctly.
var content = '<div ng-include src="marker_infoview.html"></div>';

       var markerEventListener = google.maps.event.addListener(markers[u], 'click', function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
         var compiled = $compile(content)($scope);
         stepDisplay.setContent(compiled[0]);
        }); //must be inside write new values for each marker
        
        stepDisplay.open($scope.map, markers[u]);
        
       });